# WinForms Server To Handle ASP.NET Web

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am about to convert my Winforms applications to an ASP.NET Web Application. The only question I have is the following:

My Winforms application connects to a server via TCP/IP connection (TCPClient),  and handles all requests and commands through my own custom protocols (Strings sent that are validated server side and sent back to client)

Can I keep this same Server to handle the requests from my ASP.Net Web Application (I plan on using the same protocol)?

Will there be anything I have to change within the server?  How different is migrating a Winforms application to an ASP.Net application?

Do you suggest I use WebForms or MVC?

Comment: Impossible to know without seeing the server, but if I got it right, the server knows nothing about the winforms program, they both stick to the protocol and nothing more. If that's the case, if the website keeps the protocol, the server won't notice the difference, and thus won't have to be changed at all.

Comment: Nope,  the server knows to only accept commands from a validated handshake code, and if the local variable loggedinuser,  matches the person making the request.  Other than that its just data fetch requests sent to client

Comment: I get what I am really asking,  Is using the TCPClient client class practical in an ASP.Net Web Application?

Comment: This is a compound question and far to broad to be answered in 1 specific answer. It's not just a different ballpark, it's a different continent.

Comment: @StavrosPehlivanidis There is no difference in using `TCPClient` in ASP.NET website than from a winforms program. Ultimately, it's the very same framework you run. If you use .NET Core instead of the normal .NET you could see minor API differences, but the fact remains that the connection can be done in pretty much the very same way. And in fact, it's not uncommon at all.

Comment: On the first question, this is just an guess, but in all likelyhood you can wire your webapp to work with the existing server.  Second question, that's up to you.  My experience WebForms is a more simple transition from WinForms, MVC might be a pretty big paradigm shift

Answer (score 0):

Well, we might be confusing things here some what.

You have a asp.net application. Then the question is:

asp.net webforms application

or

asp.net webform web site

While both above are similar?

Well, in the first case, a web application means that you compile your code BEFORE web deploy, and for the most part this site is to be considered the WHOLE site (the web config file is in root etc.). And any external assemblies etc. are linked at compile (or publish time). And you are as a general rule NOT EDITING and design and working against the actual web site files. In other words, the folder that holds your project CAN NOT JUST be dragged say to a web server folder and it will work.

And of course this allows you to write custom handlers for pdf files or whatever.

So you can add + hook into the http handlers.

And of course this also allows you to build say a custom logon (authentication provider).

So, you can think of a web application more like a WHOLE application - just like say all the truckloads of source files that you have for a desktop application. You THEN compile this whole big thing, and you compile down to that .exe (or .dll).
You THEN must web publish the whole thing as a application to the web server.

so this is the whole site. Things like custom logon providers, http handlers, and even trapping the Session() start can be done.

And When you web publish, then you get a standard web site, and folders and all of the SOURCE vb.net (or c#) files are removed. Just like compiling down and deploying any desktop application - the source code and files are REMOVED. Needless to say, this approach is "common" to developers coming from a desktop environment.

So no sub-sites really can be done with this model. You are hooking DIRECTLY into the IIS web server.

A web site?
That is ONLY a set of folders that you can have the IIS site work against. In fact one could argue that AFTER you publish a web application, you get "mostly" the SAME thing as a web site.

But this model with any ease cobble up a web site with say 5 pages and JUST deploy that to your local web hosting? Nope!!! - can't do that!

The reason of course is you NOT dealing with ready made web site layouts and files. You HAVE to compile the whole mess into a application.

So like deploying an desktop application you are deploying a WHOLE system.

Now, if you going to have a site with say user logons, passwords and write a custom authenticaiton provider that IIS will respect and use? Again a web site can't do that.

So again you need a code system that supports logon hooks,  and lets you control what those people can see and do. So for a line of business application? Well that quite much going to be a whole system - and thus you need control of logons, a master page(s) etc.

So the root, the config files, how they EVEN logon to your site? Everything must be just right and that config setup and file is the BASE SITE configuration for the web server. You can change authnetical providers - include custom http handles etc.

So this is a whole custom site here. And as noted, this is publish type operations.

However, asp.net for a long time ALSO supports what is called a web site.

So when the web started? Well, you just dumped web pages into some folders - maybe some hyper links to jump around. But a LOT of developers started out working this way.  And because you can DIRECT edit the files and save them back to the site? Then no real concept of a application compile or even a web publish exists in this context. It just files sitting in a web ready format and a simple set of folders.

So a asp.net web site = just folders and files - no publish.

Now for one small change, no question that a web site is nice. And BETTER is that you can say take a set of folders and just DROP them into a existing web site - your not really publishing anything, so like the old days, you just edit and copy files to the web server folders and they work. This of course common fair html files.
But IIS does support using aspx pages (files) this way also!

Since this is just SOME folders with web pages? Then you can create and build say a bunch of different folders - each having their own cute little mini-web site. And this means that publishing to your cheap $8 per month asp.net hosting is possbile. You don't need a full IIS server and the ability to manage the IIS server system. All you EVER do is just copy files to the web site. Nothing more, nothing less. As a result, you don't have use of Session() start, and even the logon events are not under your control (unless of course you rolled your own and don't use IIS security.

With simple files and folders? Then your $8 hosting site can be used.

However, all if not most low cost simple hosting sites don't support asp.net applications.

So you can think of a web publish as replacing your base web application system the hosting provider gives to you. it also why you do NOT get use of the full ASP.net and IIS configuration options for the web site (your web provider controls and has that!!!).

One huge benefit of web sites is ease of change. As noted, you can point VS to directly edit even on the live web site files!!! There is really not concept of publishing - you just editing files and saving them to the web site folder. And this is really nice for a small change - the web site will re-compile the code for you, and for a large site, you can make a change to one wee bit of code behind and the web page - just copy that page and code to the site and you are DONE!!!

With a web application? you are doing a full-re compile, re-publish to the site for ANY and all changes. (well, ok, you could sneak in and say edit/change some markup on web page, but for the most part anything that messes with controls on a page would and could very easy break the compiled .dll's that are driving that page.

> do you suggest I use WebForms or MVC?

That is a huge deal. MVC does not even have a visual designer for your web pages (you can only see and write markup).

And the whole MVC code model and whole event model is VERY different. So perhaps while a great idea to adopt MVC? (it is!!), it is darn near a whole re-write of your existing site - they work very different from asp.net webforms applications.

> to a server via TCP/IP connection (TCPClient), and handles all requests and commands through my own custom protocols

If you mean custom http handlers? No, web sites don't' support this, you have to be creating a web site application. You can't by a simple act of placing some web pages on a web site have the lower level http handlers and network stuff change - you can only do that with a web application. Same goes for the authentication provider(s) you choose - simple web sites don't allow you to build your own custom providers (but you can roll your own logon system from scratch - but you not then enjoy even simple setups that automatic secure web pages based on their memberships in given security roles.